# Use lutyuv to calculate u component from y component

Tags: ffmpeg

In FFMpeg I use as filter

```
    lutyuv="y=0.000018712*val*val+0.0027334*val+1.3141:u=gammaval(1.09)"
```

This works well. Now I want to calculate u value as a function of calculated y, something like u=1.1*previous_calculated_y*val. How can I access previously calculated y value in formula for u? Or how can I access y information in formula for u?

Example: If y value was zero I would like to get for u = 1.3141*val.

I googled and found nothing.

lutyuv="y=0.000018712*val*val+0.0027334*val+1.3141:u=gammaval(1.09)"

Comment: The lut filters don't allow that. See the geq filter. You'll have to use it twice - set new Y values, then in the 2nd instance, calculate U values.

Comment: and I guess if in second instance I want to use original value too, I would have to split the video and would need a complex filter? That's complicated but powerful.